# Returning the last day of a month

Tags: bash, shell, unix, scripting

I am trying to return the last day of the month for the month specified in my MONTHNO variable.

So when MONTHNO points to February for example given we're in April YYYYMMDD should return 20150228

```
MONTHNO=`date -d "2 month ago" "+%m"`
YEAR=`date +%Y`
YYYYMMDD=`date +%Y%m%d`
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

You can get there in a few steps. The trick here is to go to the start of the month *after* the one you're interested in, then go back one day:

```
m=$(date -d "1 month ago" "+%m")
y=$(date "+%Y")
temp=$(date -d "${y}${m}01")
d=$(date -d "$temp - 1 day" "+%Y%m%d")
```

As we're currently in March, this gives the result:

```
20150131
```

Of course, the `m` and `y` variables could be combined, saving you a step:

```
ym=$(date -d "1 month ago" "+%Y%m")
temp=$(date -d "${ym}01")
```

You could even nest the calls to `date` (though perhaps at the expense of legibility) to do it in "one step":

```
d=$(date -d "$(date -d "$(date -d "1 month ago" "+%Y%m" )01") - 1 day" "+%Y%m%d")
```